# Need coding help using "zip()" function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code for a class that I am taking. I have finished everything but the last step and was looking for some guidance or advice on how to finish it. I have included the directions and my code so far below:

Directions:

> Generate two random lists with 1000 random integers between 1 and 6 called `die1` and `die2`. Loop through the two lists (using `zip`) to return the dice in pairs (as if you rolled them) and count:
>
> - The number of 7's (add both die) rolled
> - The number of 11's (add both die). rolled
> - The number of "snake eyes" rolled
> - The number of pairs rolled

My Code:

```
# die1 list
die1 = [] # create an empty list
while len(die1) < 1000: 
    x = random.randint(1,6) # generate a random integer between 1 & 6
    die1.append(x)
print(die1)
print()

# die2 list
die2 = [] # create an empty list
while len(die2) < 1000: 
    x = random.randint(1,6) # generate a random integer between 1 & 6
    die2.append(x)
print(die2)
print()

# Zipping die1 & die2 into pairs
zipped = zip(die1,die2)
print(zipped)
print()

# Adding the Zipped Numbers Together
sum = [x+y for (x,y) in zipped]
print(sum)
print()

# Number of 7's rolled
counter1 = sum.count(7)
print('Appearances made by 7: ')
print(counter1)
print()

# Number of 11's rolled
counter2 = sum.count(11)
print('Appearances made by 11: ')
print(counter2)
print()

# Number of Snake Eyes rolled
counter3 = sum.count(2)
print('Appearances made by 2: ')
print(counter3)
print()

# Number of Pairs rolled
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does `'pairs` mean here?

Comment: @AnandGautam Given the instruction *"Loop through the two lists (using zip) to return the dice in **pairs**"*, I guess it means `print(1000)` :-)

Comment: @AnandGautam: I, too, think it's fairly obvious what the OP meant by "pairs" given their description of the two equal-length lists.

Comment: @martineau Hmm I really can't tell whether you're continuing my joke or not or what you mean :-). What **I** was saying is that Anand's question is totally justified (I upvoted it) and should be answered, as the description uses the word "pairs" at another place for something that it probably doesn't mean the second time it uses the word.

Comment: @KellyBundy: All I meant was that the question was clear-enough with respect to the meaning of the word "pairs" in "The number of pairs rolled" (reinforced by where the code ends).

Answer (score 1):

You need to count have many times, `x==y` when zipping the 2 lists

```
counter4 = sum(1 for x, y in zip(die1, die2) if x == y)
```

---

Suggestions

- use one `for` loop to fill both arrays
- don't use builtin function name `sum` to one of your variable
- loop once over the `zip` and compute all of your `counter*` : using `list.count()` will iterate the values each time

```
die1 = []
die2 = []
for _ in range(1000):
    die1.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    die2.append(random.randint(1, 6))

counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4 = 0, 0, 0, 0
for x, y in zip(die1, die2):
    die_sum = x + y
    if die_sum == 7:
        counter1 += 1
    elif die_sum == 11:
        counter2 += 1
    elif die_sum == 2:
        counter3 += 1

    if x == y:
        counter4 += 1

print('Appearances made by  7:', counter1)
print('Appearances made by 11:', counter2)
print('Appearances made by  2:', counter3)
print('Appearances of pairs: ', counter4)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import random

die1 = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(1000)]
die2 = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(1000)]

occurences = {}

die_zipped = zip(die1, die2)

for pair in die_zipped:
    pair_sum = sum(pair)
    occurences[pair_sum] = occurences.get(pair_sum, 0) + 1

total_pairs = sum(occurences.values())

print(f"{occurences[7] = }\n{occurences[11] = }\n{occurences[2] = }\n{total_pairs = }")
```

**Output:**

```
occurences[7] = 152
occurences[11] = 47
occurences[2] = 24
total_pairs = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i liked this challenge !

What about this code ?

```py
from random import randint
list1,list2 =[ [randint(1,6) for i in range(1000)] for j in range(2)]
sums = [[item1+item2,item1==item2] for item1,item2 in zip(list1,list2)]
print("Snakes eyes",len([s for s in sums if s[0]==2]))
print("Pairs",len([s for s in sums if s[1]==True]))
print("Sevens",len([s for s in sums if s[0]==7]))
print("Elevens",len([s for s in sums if s[0]==11]))


pairs = list(zip(list1,list2))
print("Pairs",pairs)
```

Sample results :

```
Snakes eyes 32
Pairs 176
Sevens 145
Elevens 50
```

```
Snakes eyes 26
Pairs 151
Sevens 164
Elevens 57
```